# why is my animation not getting triggered?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Explosion : MonoBehaviour
{
    Animator anim;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void awake()
    {
        anim = GetComponent <Animator>(); 
    }
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        Invoke("OnDisable", 2f);        
    }
    private void OnDisable()
    {
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void StartExplosion(string target)
    {
        Debug.Log("startExplosion");
        anim.SetTrigger("OnExplosion"); 

        Debug.Log("startExplosion2");
        switch (target)
        {
            case "doge":
                transform.localScale = Vector3.one * 1.2f;
                break;
            case "dogelonmas":
                transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
                break;
            case "RocketA":
                transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
                break;
            case "RocketB":
                transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
                break;
            case "samo":
                transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
                break;
            case "shiba":
                transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
                break;
            case "jindoge":
                transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
                break;
        }

        Debug.Log("startExplosion3");
    }
}
```

[image]

Hey guys, I am dying from frustration now, I'd be super grateful if anybody can help.

So I am getting the error "NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when it tries to execute anim.SetTrigger in my StartExplosion().

It is extremly frustrating to keep getting this error. As you can see I put a trigger "OnExplosion" for the condition of the explosion, and there is never a type and set up everything correctly I believe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

I see that your `Animator anim` is in a method called: `awake()`. It is important that you check the capitalization of your methods. I'm guessing you wanted to use the `Awake()` method that Unity has built-in. However, `awake()` and `Awake()` are not the same. Since `awake()` does not get called when the script instance is loaded, the method `awake()` never gets used and `Animator anim` never gets set to anything. To resolve this:

```csharp
Animator anim;
private void Awake()
{
  anim = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
}
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much ive been looking for the answer for hours and didnt recognize that

Comment: @W3 did that work out for you? Or was it just a typo between your code and writing in SO?

Comment: yes sir it did work out i cant believe that I couldnt notice it before you pointed out